# Modifying the values in a postgresql database using a time trigger?

Tags: database, postgresql, timer

I have an application to authenticate the user based on a one time password.
This password is stored in the db with the username.
I wish to keep the OTP valid only for a certain period of time after that i want to 
get rid of that particular entry.
my table uses the user name as primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any time-based triggers offered by PostgreSQL.

What you usually want to do in this situation is insert the records with an expiry time. When you look them up, use `SELECT ... FROM the_table WHERE expiry_time < current_timestamp;`.

Have a periodic cleanup job remove old expired records using an external cron job, script, or tool like PgAgent.

Comment: Is there any specific format of storing timestamps in postgres

Comment: @MayankSharma Sure, it's all documented pretty clearly and follows the SQL standard: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html